# How can I make a KDE app (Okular) register its actions with Zeitgeist?

Tags: zeitgeist, okular

I don't really enjoy Evince, and I use Okular for my pdf needs.

Okular is nice, but when I open a document with it, it's not added to my recent documents, nor appear in the fast dash file search (it does appear after a while when the locate search is activated).

I expect Okular to register his things with Nepomuk instead of Zeitgeist.

Is it possible to get either Okular or Nepomuk give that info to Zeitgeist?

Comment: Does Okular's .desktop file (/usr/share/applications) have a line like `OnlyShowIn=KDE`? If you comment that out, does it show in the Dash? No idea about it not populating the recent documents list.

Comment: @vasa1: Sorry, I didn't explain it rigth. Okular does appear in the Dash. After I open a document in Evince it appears in the recent documents section of the Dash, but if I open it with Okular (likely because it's not zeitgeist aware) it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly at the moment it is not. The integration of Zeitgeist with KDE isn't that good. It needs more work.

### More info

There is a library named [`libqzeitgeist`](http://wm161.net/2011/10/28/libqzeitgeist-0-8-0/) which can be used for gluing applications with zeitgeist. Sadly the library (gluing code) exists, but not used that much. I had plans on working on it, but got stuck up in other work.

Comment: Have there been any updates on this in the past half-decade? Per [1], this was "coming soon" in 2010, but it's still the case for me that opening PDFs in Okular doesn't trigger their being searchable in the dash, which is all I really care about myself.

[1]: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/zeitgeist-coming-to-kde/